# how crop an image evenly without loop

Tags: python, numpy, crop

Suppose I have an np.array(image)

```
img = [[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8],
       [9,10,11,12],
       [13,14,15,16]]
```

How can I divide this in to 4 crops?

```
[[1,2],    [[3,4],    [[9,10],    [[11,12],
 [5,6]]     [7,8]]     [13,14]]     [15,16]]
```

The only way I know is to use loop to specify the `img[x_start:x_end,y_start:y_end]`.
But this is very time-consuming when it comes to a large 3D Volume.
NumPy library seems to perform better by itself than the loop in some algorithms.
Btw, if I use `img.reshape(-1,2,2)`, I get the following matrix, which is not what I want:

```
[[1,2],    [[5,6],    [[9,10],    [[13,14],
 [3,4]]     [7,8]]     [11,12]]     [15,16]]
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be Numpy library but can also cv2 or something like that which I can use in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've undersdoot your question right:

```py
img = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])

out = [np.vsplit(x, 2) for x in np.hsplit(img, 2)]

for arr1 in out:
    for arr2 in arr1:
        print(arr2)
        print()
```

Prints:

```
[[1 2]
 [5 6]]

[[ 9 10]
 [13 14]]

[[3 4]
 [7 8]]

[[11 12]
 [15 16]]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I want! And I found that we can just change 
out = [np.vsplit(x, 2) for x in np.hsplit(img, 2)] to out = [np.vsplit(x, size) for x in np.hsplit(img, size)], where size is the crop size what I want

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can play with axis using `np.transpose` or `np.moveaxis` for example.

The following solution is probably not the fastest but it illustrates what you can do with these tools.

```
img = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
         [5,6,7,8],
         [9,10,11,12],
         [13,14,15,16]])
img = img.reshape(-1,2,2)
img = np.moveaxis(img, 0, 1)
img = img.reshape(-1,2,2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(img)
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [13 14]]

 [[ 3  4]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[11 12]
  [15 16]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is called a *sliding window view*. `NumPy` already has a function to do this: `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`, but the function does not take custom strides (step size of your sliding window). I have implemented my own function which gives such a *view* (requiring minimal memory overhead):

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from typing import Tuple


def get_sliding_window_2d(x: np.ndarray, width: int, height: int, rowstride: int, colstride: int):
    """
    x: np.array
    width: width of window
    height: height of window
    rowstride: horizontal window step size
    colstride: vertical window step size 
    """
    imgRows, imgCols = x.shape
    u = np.array(x.itemsize)
    return as_strided(x,
        shape=((imgRows-width)//rowstride+1, (imgCols-height)//colstride+1, width, height), 
        strides=u*(imgCols*rowstride, colstride, imgCols, 1)
    )

a = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4,4)+1
for windows in get_sliding_window_2d(a, 2, 2, 2, 2):
    for window in windows:
        print(window, end="\n\n")

#[[1 2]
# [5 6]]
#
#[[3 4]
# [7 8]]
#
#[[ 9 10]
# [13 14]]
#
#[[11 12]
# [15 16]]
```

On a related note, if you plan to use said sliding windows to blur images using a mean kernel or do edge detection or something, you can use `scipy.signal.convolve2d` (and many other similar functions) to do it.